# How to find the rank of a sparse-array list without memory leaks?

Tags: linear-algebra, memory, sparse-arrays

I have a very wide list of sparse arrays (I basically just used the numbers as an encoding mechanism for vectors of polynomials),  and I want to find out whether they're linearly independent. How would I do this without running out of memory? This shouldn't be a problem as long as they are kept in sparse form.   [image]

Edit: In the interest of replicating the bug, the vectors are of length `10460353203` and `Map[ArrayRules, wTest[2]]` gives us:

```
{{{9565939} -> 1, {4802653} -> 2, {4783213} -> 2, {4782979} -> 2,
 {4782971} -> 2, {39367} -> 1, {19927} -> 2, {19693} -> 2, 
{19685} -> 2, {487} -> 1, {253} -> 2, {245} -> 2, {19} -> 1, 
{11} -> 2, {3} -> 1, {3491567371} -> 2, {3486804085} -> 2, 
{3486784645} -> 2, {3486784411} -> 2, {3486784403} -> 2, 
{6973568803} -> 1, {_} -> 0}, 

{{9565939} -> -1, {4802653} -> -2, {39367} -> -1, {487} -> 1, 
 {253} -> 2, {245} -> 2, {19} -> 1, {11} -> 2, {3} -> 1, 
 {3491567371} -> -2, {3486804085} -> -2, {6973568803} -> -1, {_} -> 0}, 

{{9565939} -> 1, {4802653} -> 2, {4783213} -> -2, 
 {4782979} -> -2, {4782971} -> -2, {39367} -> 1, 
 {19927} -> -2, {19693} -> -2, {19685} -> -2, {487} -> 1, 
 {253} -> 2, {245} -> 2, {19} -> 1, {11} -> 2, {3} -> 1, 
 {3491567371} -> 2, {3486804085} -> 2, {3486784645} -> -2, 
 {3486784411} -> -2, {3486784403} -> -2, {6973568803} -> 1, {_} -> 0}, 

{{2324522935} -> -2, {774840979} -> -2, {258280327} -> -2, 
 {86093443} -> -2, {28697815} -> -2, {4802653} -> 2, 
 {4783213} -> 2, {4782979} -> 2, {4782971} -> 2, {3188647} -> -2, 
 {1062883} -> -2, {354295} -> -2, {118099} -> -2, {19927} -> 2, 
 {19693} -> 2, {19685} -> 2, {13123} -> -2, {4375} -> -2, 
 {1459} -> -2, {253} -> 2, {245} -> 2, {163} -> -2, {55} -> -2, 
 {11} -> 2, {7} -> -2, {3491567371} -> 2, {3486804085} -> 2, 
 {3486784645} -> 2, {3486784411} -> 2, {3486784403} -> 2, {_} -> 0}, 

{{2324522935} -> 4, {774840979} -> 4, {4802653} -> -4, 
 {3188647} -> 4, {253} -> 4, {245} -> 4, {163} -> -4, {55} -> -4, 
 {11} -> 4, {7} -> -4, {3491567371} -> -4, {3486804085} -> -4, {_} -> 0}, 


{{258280327} -> 8, {86093443} -> 8, {28697815} -> 8, 
 {4783213} -> -8, {4782979} -> -8, {4782971} -> -8, 
 {1062883} -> 8, {354295} -> 8, {118099} -> 8, {19927} -> -8,
 {19693} -> -8, {19685} -> -8, {13123} -> 8, {4375} -> 8, 
 {1459} -> 8, {3486784645} -> -8, {3486784411} -> -8, 
 {3486784403} -> -8, {_} -> 0}}
```

Comment: `MatrixRank[wTest[2].wTest[2]\[Transpose]]`?

Comment: I might consider doing a preliminary conversion like `wt = SparseArray[wTest[2]]` before doing Henrik's suggestion.

Comment: It crashes the kernel in Mathematica 11.0 Is this improved in newer versions?

Comment: We'd have no way of knowing since we don't have your `SparseArray[]` objects.

Comment: I've made a manual function to multiply by the transpose: `timesTranspose[a_] := Array[a[[#1]].a[[#2]] &  , {Length[a], Length[a]}] ` and this seems to work well enough for small numbers and not crash when applied to `wTest[2]` .

Comment: I've added the sparse array data into the post.

Comment: Find the list of all indices used (that is, where nonzero elements appear). Make substitutions to have new indices from 1 to the length of that list. Then dense linear algebra can be used.